# How to retrieve information from database using name

Tags: android

I am working on a project where I want to search for name and retrieve all the information with that name from database. 
Can anyone suggest something??

Answer (score 0):

You should design your sql or similar db table(s) in a way that, name is some kind of primary key and other columns store related information. This has actually more to do with how you design your database and is less android specific.